# Keynote record slideshow with external mic

Tags: macos, keynote, recording, slideshow

I've looked for hours on how to record a slideshow with an external USB microphone but I didn't find anything.

Is it possible to change the audio input in Keynote to an external mic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keynote uses the system sound input device, set in System Preferences → Sound → Input. Choose your preferred connected input device from this list, then start the recording in Keynote.

[image]